# nginx + nodejs proxy error

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

```
2017/10/10 10:22:26 [crit] 1289#0: *1 connect() to 127.0.0.1:8080 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 81.x.x.x, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "mydomain.com"
```

why does this not work?

I can access the 127.0.0.1:8080 via curl but nginx just displays a 502 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by disabling SELinux which should not have been enabled in the first place.